# Make a bash PS1 that counts streak of 'correct' commands

Tags: bash, prompt

My goal is to have a bash prompt that displays a shortened username, a shortened path in blue, and a counter variable that gets reset every time I mistype a command (which I will check with `$?`, though this is not strictly the same).

Right now, my `~/.bashrc` has:

```
counter=0
#should increment counter if no errors, else reset counter
PROMPT_COMMAND="if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ((counter++)); else counter=0; fi"
PS1='(${USER:0:3}@\[\e[0;34m\]$(basename $(dirname $PWD))/$(basename $PWD)\[\e[m\])[$counter]\\$ '
```

This displays:

```
(use@//home)[17]$
```

My main problem is that counter is never reset to zero when I get a nonzero exit status. I can run the command in `PROMPT_COMMAND` after a failed command such as `aasdjfasdf` and `echo $counter` will show a `0` (actually, a `1`, since PROMPT_COMMAND increments it immediately).

My other lesser problem is that in the root directory my prompt will display

```
(use@///)[11]$
```

which is less than ideal (the 3 /'s). I'm not sure how to fix that either, but at least it's not as big of a deal.

How do I get PROMPT_COMMAND to correctly increment and reset counter?

**edit**: Here is my PS1 that does everything I want, in case others are curious:

```
counter=0
PROMPT_COMMAND='if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ((counter++)); else counter=0; fi;'
PS1='(\[\e[4m\]${USER:0:3}\[\e[0m\]@\[\e[34m\]${PWD:${#PWD}<15?0:(-15)}\[\e[m\])[$counter]\\$ '
```

Comment: @Sinjai, you are wrong. Have you tried this?

Comment: I am wrong – I tested it, but poorly. Classic single vs double quotes issue. If you define PS1 properly as you've shown above, $counter will remain in the string verbatim and be re-expanded each time $PS1 is used by the shell, as intended. I'm going to delete my comment to avoid wasting future visitors' time (and out of shame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change PROMPT_COMMAND to be:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then counter=$((counter+1)); else counter=0; fi'
```

Use single-quotes to prevent premature expansion of `$?`, and use direct assignment for the incremented value of `counter`.

Comment: This would increment the counter even if you just press Enter.