# history -c does not reset $HISTCMD to 1

Tags: bash, command-history

TL;DR: If your history begins to truncate (e.g., your `HISTSIZE` is 400 but your history number is 500), resetting your history with `history -c` will clear `HISTSIZE` or fewer lines from your history, and subtract that many from your history number, but will not reset it to 0 (in the example, it would reset it to 100). How can I completely reset the history number back to 0?

---

Bash 4.2 (and also on 4.4). I want my history numbers to be under 4 digits. relevant bashrc sections:

```
HISTSIZE=99
HISTFILESIZE=100
#ignores back-to-back duplicate commands, not those that start with a space
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
#ignore commands fewer than 5 characters long because we can type those
HISTIGNORE="?:??:???:????:?????:history"
```

the history number as seen with `history` or `\!` in the PS1 will obviously go beyond these values. I want to be able to reset the history number down to ~100 when it goes above 1,000.

`history -c` clears the terminal history, but that only reduces the history number by the amount of commands that it cleared, e.g.:

```
j:~$ history | wc -l
99
j:~$ echo $HISTFILESIZE
100
j:~$ echo $HISTCMD 
1203
j:~$ history -c
j:~$ echo $HISTCMD
1106
```

So... how do I drop the history number down to a smaller number, such as `$HIST(FILE)SIZE`. This is in a tmux session, but I don't think that should matter.

Aside: is there a method to get the current history number as a variable that requires fewer pipes than the one I'm currently using? EDIT: as Jeff mentioned, `$HISTCMD` stores this value.

None of the solutions provided work. Here's what they do with `set -x`:

[image: history -c doesn't clear history]

Comment: along the way, there's `$HISTCMD`, unless it's been unset.

Comment: I think a large part of your question [has already been answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434397/how-to-reset-the-bash-command-number)

Comment: @JeffSchaller, the command number, AFAIK, is different than the history number. one is `\#` and one is `\!`. One changes with `history -c` and one doesn't

Comment: There is a [solution on here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48116/265604). it seems that four steps are needed. Read the description for the reason of `HISTFILESIZE=$HISTSIZE`.

Comment: @Isaac, I added a picture to show that solution failing.

Comment: It works here. Why don't you update bash? The 4.2 version is from 2011-02-13 (7 years old).

Comment: @Isaac, Centos 7 on work computers. =(

Comment: @Isaac, the problem persists on bash 4.4.23.